# How to Run Windows Mobile 6.5 Applications Using Emulator From Command Line

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, emulation, windows-mobile-6.5

I can launch my windows mobile application using the emulator via visual studio in the normal fashion, but i would like to run my application from the command line and preferably pass in some parameters. Is this possible?

I can launch the emulator ONLY using the command line like so:

`DeviceEmulator.exe example.bin`

But how can i possibly launch my application using this emulator via the command line?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you save the state of your emulator then you can run the created .DESS file and pick up right where the saved state left off.  You can put this in a batch file:

start DeviceEmulator.exe /s "C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Microsoft\Device Emulator{E4FC2BC5-3AC4-452C-A893-AD4F273C3A7C}.dess" /nosecurityprompt /memsize 256

You'll need to change the path and file name to match your system.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa188169%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is a list of the DeviceEmulator.exe command line switches.

If you're looking for a more elegant solution, you can control DeviceEmulator.exe via a COM interface.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb887543.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

**-->** **Go to this file directory** C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Device Emulator\1.0\"

**-->** **Use this command** "DeviceEmulator.exe"  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Mobile 6.5.3 DTK\PocketPC\Deviceemulation\0409\PPC_USA_GSM_VR.BIN" /a /battery /batterycharge 100 /cpucore ARMv5 /memsize 256 /s "E:\MyCustomEmulator.dess" /skin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Mobile 6.5.3 DTK\PocketPC\Deviceemulation\Pocket_PC_Phone\Pocket_PC_PE.xml" /tooltips ON /vfp false /vmname "My Custom Emulator" /z /speakerphone 7

**Note:**
.dess file Save the Emulator state. you can resume that saved state later.
.BIN is the actual emulator os. it is available when installing the windows mobile 6.5 sdks
.xml is the outer skin .

**For more Details** [Visit this microsoft documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/aa188169(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)